# How to obtain the value through the nested objects in Reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs, undefined

I am new to the Reactjs development and currently working on a personal fun personal project. So I have JSON file and the contents are:

```
{
  "btcinr": {
    "base_unit": "btc",
    "quote_unit": "inr",
    "low": "479200.0",
    "high": "509949.0",
    "last": "500003.0",
    "type": "SPOT",
    "open": 493000.0,
    "volume": "48.0567",
    "sell": "503000.0",
    "buy": "500003.0",
    "at": 1584867246,
    "name": "BTC/INR"
  }
}
```

I have following code in my render method:

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    items : [],
    isLoading: true,
  }
}


  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('JSON API LINK')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
         items: data,
         isLoading: false,
        })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

  render() {

const list = this.state.items.btcinr && Object.keys(this.state.items.btcinr);
console.log(list);


    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isLoading ? <h1>Fetching data </h1> :

            list.map( 
              (ticker) => 
              <li>{ticker}</li>

              )
        }

      </div>
    );}
  }

export default App;
```

What I want the output is the value of last. But when I go through list.last I get error that

> cannot read the proparty "last" of undefined.

Comment: You need to build the component by passing properties to it. Or to build the values in the state, but leave that for later, look here how to pass props to components. [How to pass props from one class to another in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662893/how-to-pass-props-from-one-class-to-another-in-react-js)

Comment: Can you paste the full code of your JSX file with state etc?

Comment: `list` is an array of the **keys**. you'd probably want to use `this.state.items.btcinr.last`

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb I have edited the code and inserted full code.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is not correct since you have the **JSON** as a response and you need to check if **btcinr** key exists in your **items** state then you need to make a list of keys available in **btcinr**.

This code should solve your problem:

```
render() {
const { items } = this.state;
let list = [];
if(items.hasOwnProperty('btcinr')){
  list = Object.keys(items.btcinr);
}
return (
  <div>
    {list.map(ticker => (
      <li>{ticker}</li>
    ))}
  </div>
);}
```

If you want to get the last property of btcinr you can use this code:

```
if(items.hasOwnProperty('btcinr')){
      const last = items.btcinr.last;
  }
```

And if you want to get the value of the last index from the list of keys, then you can use this code:

```
if(items.hasOwnProperty('btcinr')){
      list = Object.keys(items.btcinr);
      const last = list[list.length];
  }
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for replying. What I want to do is obtain the value of last property in btcinr, and still using the solution you provided i cannot retrieve that value. What can be done?

Comment: I have Eddited my answer as per your requirement. Hope this solves your problem