# Reactjs component - one vs many

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to figure out the best way to make a component that can handle different scenarios. I'm not sure if the best practice would be to make multiple components or one component to handle it all.

Imagine a frontpage were you have 3 different entrances like recent products, blogpost or Instagram pictured. Each entrance use a component called featured and inside that component I should render either products, blogpost or Instagram pictures. Everything for the layout is the same, its just the items in the grid that needs to change. What would be the best way to solve this? one component with 3 different sub-components or 3 components with one for each type.

I know how to make 3 different components, but I'm not sure how to make one component to handle subcomponents.

This could be the component and the "grid-item--product" could also be a "grid-item--blogpost or "grid-item--Instagram" - "grid" could also be a "two-col" or "three-col".

```
<div className="featured">
    <div className="featured--content">
        <div className="grid four-col">
            <grid-item--product />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this could be where I would call the component and hopefully be able to handle which component should be rendered inside and what the grid should be for this feature.

```
<div className="frontpage-route">
    <h2>Frontpage Route</h2> 
    <Featured />
</div>
```

Can you help me? I would love an example if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is the [children](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) prop.  You can add the `children` prop to `Featured` and just pass the correct children to it.  See an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-swirles-d3gsf?file=/src/App.js):

```
const Featured = ({ children, numColumns = "one" }) => (
  <div className="featured">
    <div className="featured--content">
       <div className={`grid ${numColumns}-col`}>
         {children}
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
)

const App = () => (
  <div className="frontpage-route">
    <h1>Frontpage Route</h1>

    <h2>Products</h2>
    <Featured numColumns="two">
      <grid-item--product />
      <grid-item--product />
    </Featured>

    <h2>Blogs</h2>
    <Featured numColumns="three">
      <grid-item--blog />
      <grid-item--blog />
    </Featured>

    <h2>Instagram</h2>
    <Featured>
      <grid-item--instagram />
      <grid-item--instagram />
    </Featured>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: But i also need to be able to set the grid so that one featured is with four-col grid but another use maybe two-col. Is this possible or do i then have to make 1 component for each?

Comment: Add another prop to featured to set the number of columns.  I'll update the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use consitional rendering and three boolean variables to display components.
e.g:

```
<div className="featured">
   <div className="featured--content">
      <div className="grid four-col">
        {product && <grid-item--product />}  //if product var is true this component renders  
        {blogpost  && <grid-item--blogpost />}  //if blogpost var is true this component renders 
        {instagram && <grid-item--instagram />}  //if instagram var is true this component renders  
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But i also need to be able to set the grid so that one featured is with four-col grid but another use maybe two-col. Is this possible or do i then have to make 1 component for each?

Comment: In that case you can have one common child component for your blogpost, Instagram and products. Then pass your grids or you can create an object and pass it to your child compnent as prop. something similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40663229/10703114